Help! Is this water damage?
We had a water loss at our house a year and a half ago. The flooding came up to/into this bathroom however, in the beginning insurance said the tile was not impacted. Fine. We accepted that.
However, moving back in, we saw that the tile had cracked around the door frame on both sides of the door and the door no longer closes properly. It doesn’t latch. Insurance is telling us they’re still no damage and that the cracking is normal, and the door is not closing because the hinges are installed in properly.
However, no one removed the door and it was closing fine before the water loss.
Could there be something else going on? Swollen wood anywhere? What are we missing? We’d like to continue fighting this if there is actual damage happening underneath/on the sides.
Pictures:(https://imgur.com/a/X8hO347)

Notice that the duplicate linked above is your question--it's just been revised by the community to present a proper title (without begging). Please see [ask] and take the [tour].
